# Meaning of terms $O(\cdot)$ ("terms order at most") and $o(\cdot)$ ("terms of smaller order than")?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

In the paper "Risk aversion in the small and in the large" (1964) by John Pratt, a formula is derived for the approximation of the risk premium:

$r_p \approx 0.5 \times \sigma^2 \times r(x)$.

The risk can be represented with a binary outcome of either $x_\text{low}$ or $x_\text{high}$.

$p=$ probability of a high outcome

$\Delta=x_\text{high} - x_\text{low}$

In which $\sigma^2=\Delta^2p(1-p)$

If utility would be quantified with $\ln(x)$ then $r(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

So,

$rp \approx 0.5\Delta^2p(1-p)\frac{1}{x}$

If you choose the certainty equivalent as $x$, the approximation is actually more precise than when you choose $x$. But you need the output of the formula: the risk premium, to use it ($CE$). So this is clearly not possible.

What do the terms: $O()$ and $o()$ mean, and can they be represented with a mathematical formula?

---

In the attachments I have added the first four pages of the John Pratt paper and two pictures.

The first picture shows the quantification of the most common risk preference: risk aversion.

The second picture shows the risk premia for the whole continuum of the expected $x$ values. The risk premium is the highest somewhere in the middle, since the variance: $\Delta^2p(1-p)$, is the highest at p=50%. The red line shows the exact risk premium. Arp11 shows the approximation in which the $CE$ is used as $x$ and to calculate $p$ ($p=\frac{CE-x_\text{low}}{x_\text{high}-x_\text{low}}$). In Arp22 $E(x)$ is used as the $x$ value and to derive $p$ ($p=\frac{E(x)-x_\text{low}}{x_\text{high}-x_\text{low}}$).

Although Arp11 seems to be the best interpretation of the formula, Arp22 is the closest approximation.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although Arp11 seems to be the best interpretation of the formula, Arp22 is the closest approximation.* mistake:

Although Arp22 seems to be the best interpretation of the formula with E(x) as x, Arp11 is the closest approximation.

Comment: To answer the question somewhere in the middle: O() usually refers to the Landau Symbols: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. I'm a bit confused by all the rest though

Comment: Please use LaTeX to format your mathematics. Also, inserting screenshots of large amount of text, as you have done here, is frowned upon.

Comment: In this context, the $O$ and $o$ notations are used for Taylor (power series) expansions of functions.  Their precise meanings can be found by consulting any account of the Taylor Theorem with remainder (there are a couple of different versions, but they lead to the same conclusions).

Comment: Welcome to CV, david laport.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). For Big-O:

> in mathematics, it is commonly used to describe how closely a finite series approximates a given function, especially in the case of a truncated Taylor series or asymptotic expansion

And about little-o:

> The difference between the earlier definition for the big-O notation and the present definition of little-o, is that while the former has to be true for at least one constant M, the latter must hold for every positive constant ε, however small.[5] In this way, little-o notation makes a stronger statement than the corresponding big-O notation: every function that is little-o of g is also big-O of g, but not every function that is big-O of g is also little-o of g.

Comment: The precise derivation of the formula with O() and o() are shown on page 125 in the attachments, in formulas 4a until 5.
With final formula: rp = 0.5*σ^2*r(x) + o(σ^2)